# how can set states in hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have nested state for attributes of form validation in a class based component, now I need to refactor my code from class base to functional base component, I also have method for working and updating states, now, I don't know how can I refactor method and update states in `setState`, my code is:

```
const [userForm, setUserForm] = useState({
    name: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Name...'
        },
        value: '',
        validation: {
            required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        used: false,
    },
    password: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
            type: 'password',
            placeholder: 'Password...'
        },
        value: '',
        validation: {
            required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        used: false,
    },
    email: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
            type: 'text',
            palceholder: 'Email...'
        },
        value: '',
        validation: {
            required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        used: false,
    }
})
```

also a method for updating values:

```
 submitDataHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    const { form: { name, email, password } } = this.state;
    const finalOrders = {
        totalPrice: this.state.totalPrice,
        numbers: this.state.addCounter,
        name: name.value,
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    }
    this.setState({ purchased: true })
    axios.post('/final-order.json', finalOrders)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ loading: false, purchased: false })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ loading: false, purchased: false })
        })
    console.log({ name: name.value, email: email.value, password: password.value })
    console.log(`Total Price: ${this.state.totalPrice}`)
    console.log(`Number of Order: ${this.state.addCounter}`)
}
```

and also another method:

```
 changeDataHandler = (value, key) => {
    const { form } = this.state;
    const currentForm = { ...form };
    currentForm[key].value = value;
    currentForm.valid = this.checkValidation(currentForm[key].value, currentForm[key].validation)
    currentForm.used = true
    this.setState({ form: currentForm })
```

}

Comment: What or where are you stuck in the conversion? Do you have a separate `loading` state? Looks like you are missing a lot of the defined state that `submitDataHandler` accesses. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example, and details about what/where you have an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have individual state variables for all the other state:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
const [addCounter, setAddCounter] = useState(0);
const [purchased, setPurchased] = useState(false);
const [userForm, setUserForm] = useState({ ... });

submitDataHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);
    
  const { name, email, password } = userForm;
  const finalOrders = {
    totalPrice,
    numbers: addCounter,
    name: name.value,
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value
  }

  setPurchased(true);

  axios.post('/final-order.json', finalOrders)
    .then((response) => {
      // happy path, handle success
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // sad path, handle error
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setPurchased(false);
    });
    
    console.log({ name: name.value, email: email.value, password: password.value });
    console.log(`Total Price: ${totalPrice}`);
    console.log(`Number of Order: ${addCounter}`);
};
```

Unlike `setState` of class-based components, the `useState` state setter ***doesn't*** shallow merge new state, so you will need to manage this. Fortunately if you are familiar with functional state update the pattern is essentially the same, shallow copy each state property you intend to update.

```
changeDataHandler = (value, key) => {
  setUserForm(userForm => ({
    ...userForm,
    [key]: {
      ...userForm[key],
      value,
      valid: checkValidation(userForm[key].value, userForm[key].validation),
      used: true,
    },
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Mr. @Drew Reese, it works correctly